# Animation on scroll plugin not working in Nuxt version 2 after deploying to Firebase hosting using cloud functions

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, aos.js

I am using the animate on scroll library via npm in my Nuxt.js site. When I add it to my plugins/aos.js, and configure it in the nuxt.config.js plugin, it works just well. But when I try deploying to Firebase hosting with cloud functions, it doesn't work.

Here is my plugins/aos.js file

```
 import AOS from "aos";
 
 import "aos/dist/aos.css";
 
 export default ({ app }) = {   app.AOS = new AOS.init({ disable:
 "phone" }); };
```

This is my nuxt.config.js file

```
 export default {   mode: "universal",
 
   head: {
     title: process.env.npm_package_name || "",
     meta: [
       { charset: "utf-8" },
       { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
       {
         hid: "description",
         name: "description",
         content: process.env.npm_package_description || ""
       }
     ],
     link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }]   },
      loading: { color: "#fff" },
      css: [],
     plugins: [{ src: "@/plugins/aos", mode: "server" }],
     buildModules: [],
     modules: ["@nuxtjs/vendor"],
      buildDir: "../functions/nuxt",   build: {
     publicPath: "/",
     extractCSS: true,
    
     extend(config, ctx) {}   } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of SSR. I just got this working myself.

Rename `aos.js` to `aos.client.js` to make sure it's only loaded on the client.

In that file I have

```js
import AOS from 'aos'

export default ({ app }) => {
  app.AOS = AOS.init({
    offset: 250,
    once: true,
  })
}
```